# Is Laravel-Backpack Admin package compatible with MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to use Laravel-backpack admin package with MongoDB and getting bunch of errors.

I'm wondering Is backpack compatible with using MongoDB as Database?

Comment: Please consider posting any relevant error messages as well.

Comment: Ref. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/802 - tabacitu commented on Jan 29, 2018: "Quick update: it has been reported that Backpack works well with MongoDB, using this excellent package: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb".

Comment: I can confirm tabacitu has said that :-)